# Modsecurity OWASP Core Rule Set - base64 false positive rule 941170

Tags: nginx, base64, owasp, mod-security

We use ModSecurity 3.X for NGIX with the OWASP core rule set.

We have a problem with image in base64 and the rule `941170`.

The pattern of the rule is

```
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent|REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "@rx (?i)(?:\W|^)(?:javascript:(?:[\s\S]+[=\\\(\[\.<]|[\s\S]*?(?:\bname\b|\\[ux]\d))|data:(?:(?:[a-z]\w+\/\w[\w+-]+\w)?[;,]|[\s\S]*?;[\s\S]*?\b(?:base64|charset=)|[\s\S]*?,[\s\S]*?<[\s\S]*?\w[\s\S]*?>))|@\W*?i\W*?m\W*?p\W*?o\W*?r\W*?t\W*?(?:\/\*[\s\S]*?)?(?:[\"']|\W*?u\W*?r\W*?l[\s\S]*?\()|\W*?-\W*?m\W*?o\W*?z\W*?-\W*?b\W*?i\W*?n\W*?d\W*?i\W*?n\W*?g[\s\S]*?:[\s\S]*?\W*?u\W*?r\W*?l[\s\S]*?\("
```

Log:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token
Set-Cookie: SESSION_ID=b57248f3aa2ac2c169e664b1862e49ed_; path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 16:06:52 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8; boundary=xYzZY
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Security-Policy, Location
Content-Length: 67
Server: nginx
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

---RleKJMgH---H--
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i)(?:\W|^)(?:javascript:(?:[\s\S]+[=\\\(\[\.<]|[\s\S]*?(?:\bname\b|\\[ux]\d))|data:(?:(?:[a-z]\w+\/\w[\w+-]+\w)?[;,]|[\s\S]*?;[\s\S]*?\b(?:base64|charset=)|[\s\S]*?,[\s\S]*?<[\s\S]*?\w[\s\S]*?>))|@\ (188 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:screen' (Value: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCI (47619 characters omitted)' ) [file "/etc/nginx/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "236"] [id "941170"] [rev ""] [msg "NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: Attribute Injection"] [data "Matched Data: data:image/jpeg; found within ARGS:screen: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (47576 characters omitted)"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.2.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A3"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "CAPEC-242"] [hostname "192.168.1.1"] [uri "/wsrfef.subirArchivo"] [unique_id "1633536412"] [ref "o0,16v1288,47719t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:jsDecode,t:cssDecode,t:removeNulls"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `5' ) [file "/etc/nginx/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "80"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.2.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "192.168.1.1"] [uri "/wsrfef.subirArchivo"] [unique_id "1633536412"] [ref ""]
```

Now we are using the `SecRuleUpdateTargetById 941170 "!ARGS:screen"` command but this way the rest of the checks are not applied

Is there any way to modify the pattern of the rule so that it does not detect base64 as NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: Attribute Injection?

**UPDATE**

I have another false positive with page called /organirama and button with btn-warning class. The OWASP detects the page name and the btn-warning class as an Oracle SQL Information Leakage.

```
---X96Job8w---A--
[26/Oct/2021:09:43:43 +0200] 1635234223 2.152.144.73 57524 10.10.2.11 443
---X96Job8w---B--
GET /organigrama HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Referer: domain.net/inicio
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Host: domain.net
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: SESSION_ID=06699c6dd9769a905e968ba2932edd75
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9

---X96Job8w---D--

---X96Job8w---E--

ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i:ORA-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|java\.sql\.SQLException|Oracle error|Oracle.*Driver|Warning.*oci_.*|Warning.*ora_.*)' against variable `RESPONSE_BODY' (Value: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">\x0a<html>\x0a  <head>\x0a    <!--\x0 (304143 characters omitted)' ) [file "/etc/nginx/coreruleset/rules/RESPONSE-951-DATA-LEAKAGES-SQL.conf"] [line "69"] [id "951120"] [rev ""] [msg "Oracle SQL Information Leakage"] [data "Matched Data: warning" title="F\xc3\xbatbol  -  Infantil  -  Infantil +40 Masculino">\x0d\x0a              <strong>F\xc3\xbatbol  -  Infantil  -  Infantil +40 Masculino</strong>\x0d\x0a            </button>\x0d\x0a          </div> (420740 characters omitted)"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-oracle"] [tag "attack-disclosure"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/118/116/54"] [hostname "192.168.1.1"] [uri "/organigrama"] [unique_id "1635235649"] [ref "o33323,193787v756,227110"]
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 4). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `4' against variable `TX:OUTBOUND_ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `5' ) [file "/etc/nginx/coreruleset/rules/RESPONSE-959-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "68"] [id "959100"] [rev ""] [msg "Outbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [data ""] [severity "0"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "anomaly-evaluation"] [hostname "192.168.1.1"] [uri "/organigrama"] [unique_id "1635235649"] [ref ""]
```

I try not to apply the rule for `RESPONSE BODY` but keep catching it

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /organigrama" \
    "id:1030,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=959100;RESPONSE_BODY"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SecRuleUpdateTargetById` rule exclusion you provided looks good to me.

To be clear, the effect of that rule exclusion is:

- Rule 941170 no longer applies to the `screen` argument
- Rule 941170 still applies to all other arguments as usual
- All other rules still apply to all arguments, including `screen`, as usual

Is there a reason you're not happy with this?

If you're running a super-high security setup which means that the `SecRuleUpdateTargetById` rule exclusion is too coarse, two suggestions I would make:

- If appropriate for your web application, limit the rule exclusion for rule 941170 to *only* apply to the `screen` argument **and** *only* for a given location (for example, only for requests to `/login.php`)
- Limit the rule exclusion for rule 941170 to *only* apply to the `screen` argument **and** *only* when `screen` begins with the string `data:image/jpeg;base64`

You could even combine both of those suggestions to be *extremely* specific.

If either, or both, of those sound applicable to your situation, let me know if you would like help to put those rule exclusions together.

Also, what paranoia level are you currently running in, out of interest?

---

Regarding your suggestion to modify rule 941170's regular expression, it's a bad idea to directly modify third-party rules, such as the Core Rule Set rules. You essentially end up creating your own fork of the rule set, and you're left with the responsibility for maintaining any modifications you make. Upgrading the rule set would become difficult: you would have to remember to keep re-applying, and possibly change, your modifications. In short: **rule exclusions are the way to go!**

---

### Update

The second rule exclusion described above may look something like this:

```
#
# -- CRS Rule Exclusion: 941170 - NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: Attribute
#                                 Injection
#
# Disable this rule for the "screen" argument when it begins with the string
# "data:image/jpeg;base64,". This resolves a false positive caused by base64
# encoded images.
#
SecRule ARGS:screen "@beginsWith data:image/jpeg;base64," \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941170;ARGS:screen"
```

The exclusion would need to be placed **before** the directive(s) that includes the Core Rule Set.

---

### Update 2

Regarding your second false positive: are you running an Oracle SQL server? Rule 951120 is Oracle SQL specific. If you are not running such a server, I would recommend disabling that rule, like so:

```
#
# -- CRS Rule Exclusion: 951120 - Oracle SQL Information Leakage
#
# Disable this Oracle SQL specific rule, as the rule causes false positives for
# the /organirama page and the Oracle SQL server/service is not in use.
#
SecRuleRemoveById 951120
```

This exclusion would need to be placed **after** the directive(s) that includes the Core Rule Set.

Comment: Thank I am running a normal web application, but it is my first time using ModSecurity. I would like to learn how to apply the second suggestion. can you help me?

Comment: Certainly. See the update to my original answer above.

Comment: Can you help me with another false positive ? I update my question.

Comment: All good: see my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your help